# Как можно расположить блоки по кругу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует расположение `div` по кругу и особенно кроссбраузерно.
По ссылке: http://themegret.com/demo/html/egret/ видно что SVG не применялось, но мне так и не ясно каким образом расположены блоки с содержимым по кругу.

Comment: Может быть это делалось с использованием SVG?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow нету там вроде бы svg : http://themegret.com/demo/html/egret/

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. он бесполезен для базы знаний: поискивики (пока) не научились извлекать смысл вопроса из картинки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можно же просто отредактировать вопрос, зачем же сразу закрывать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Всё это делается с помощью CSS3 `transfrom` (в том числе по ссылке, указанной вами). Для этого создаётся контейнер, у которого все дети одинаковой ширины и высоты имеют `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0`, то есть расположены друг за другом. Далее всем детям присвоен `transform-origin: 50% 200% 0;` для того, чтобы их вращать вокруг точки которая расположена под блоками, а не по центру всех картинок (значение по умолчанию `50% 50% 0`), то есть в нашем случае Y-смещение равно `200%`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий простой пример:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 200% 0;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red">
  </div>

  <div class="orange">
  </div>

  <div class="yellow">
  </div>

  <div class="green">
  </div>

  <div class="lightblue">
  </div>

  <div class="blue">
  </div>

  <div class="purple">
  </div>
</div>
```