# Позиционирование нескольких div друг под другом

Tags: css3

Имеется вот такая конструкция:

```
<div CLASS="PARENT">
    <div CLASS="CHILD"></div>
    <div CLASS="CHILD"></div>
    ...
    <div CLASS="CHILD"></div>
</div>
```

И детей с классом CHILD может быть произвольное неизвестное количество. Как сделать так, чтобы дети располагались строго друг под другом по оси Z?
Причём необходимо чтобы PARENT принимал размер содержимого (самого верхнего, видимого глазу блока).

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы хотите наложить элементы друг на друга, чтобы при этом PARENT целиком оборачивал эти элементы?

Comment: Элементы сложены "в стопку" друг под другом и все одного размера. Нужно, чтобы родительский блок принимал размеры самого верхнего, видимого элемента.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602115/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно такой вариант прокатит:

[JsFiddle >>](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/a2x1t967/)

Насколько я понял, у вас и так есть JS динамичного создания элементов. Останется туда добавить строчку сравнения высот, последний if:

```js
document.getElementById('create').addEventListener('click', function(){
  //При клике создали div, сделали класс CHILD
  let child = document.createElement('div');
      child.className = "CHILD";
  
  //Этот кусок не важен. Для случайного наполнения текстом
  let text = "";
  let u = Math.floor( Math.random()*245 + 5 );
  for(let i = 0; i < u; i++){ text += "test "; }
  child.innerHTML = text;
  
  //Пихаем созданный элемент в нужный div.
  let mama = document.getElementById('MAMA');
  mama.appendChild(child);
  
  //Рассчитываем высоту созданного элемента и сравниваем с высотой общего div
  let H = child.clientHeight;
  if( mama.clientHeight < H ) { 
  //Если оказалось меньше - меняем высоту.
    mama.style.height = H + 'px'; 
  }
});
```

```css
#MAMA {width: 400px; border: 5px solid #123;}

.CHILD {position: absolute; width: 400px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<button id="create">Создать</button>
<div id="MAMA"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый очевидный способ выстроить блоки по оси z - абсолютное позиционирование(кроме первого, т.к он определяет размер родителя). JS для демонстрации: чтобы отправить первый блок в конец списка - кликните по нему.

```js
$('.child').click(function(){
 $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
})
```

```css
.parent{
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.child{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
}
.child:first-child{
 position:relative;
 z-index:99;
}
#child1{
 background:red;
 height:30px;
}
#child2{
 background:green;
 height:40px;
}
#child3{
 background:blue;
 height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child" id="child1"></div>
 <div class="child" id="child2"></div>
 <div class="child" id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Такое решение я воспроизводил, но оно мной было отвергнуто, т.к. блоки динамически вставляются и удаляются. Много лишнего JS'а получится(

Comment: Прочитал про z-index в CSS. Возможно ли выстроить элементы с position: relative как указано при помощи него?

Comment: Оно, конечно, можно, НО: 1)элементы с position:relative все влияют на размер родителя; 2) Придется позиционировать каждого потомка либо вручную, либо тем же js.

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```js
var cardDeck = $('.card-deck');
var firstCard = $('.card-deck .card').first();

$('.card-deck').css({height: firstCard.outerHeight(), width: firstCard.outerWidth()});

$('.card').each(function(index){
  $(this).on("click", function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.card-deck {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 240px;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
  color: white;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
.card-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.card-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.card-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.card + .card {
  z-index: 1; // начинаем отсчет карт с конца
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card card-red">Red card</div>
  <div class="card card-blue">Blue card</div>
  <div class="card card-green">Green card</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это немного не то, что я имел ввиду. Так блоки будут позиционироваться по оси У.

Comment: Дожны накладываться друг на друга полностью. Все блоки одного размера.

Comment: Я думаю он хочет сделать типа "карточной колоды".. Где элементы друг на друге по оси Z

Comment: Сравнение в точку, ХD

Comment: @ИльяКолдунов, изменил еще раз пример :)